# jQuery AJAX response not displaying

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple AJAX call, and a php script that echos. For some reason, my AJAX is not logging the response. The script executes, but it writes onto a different page. I think there's a problem with my Javascript, but the same thing works on other files perfectly fine. Any insight would be great.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

This is the PHP echo that I tested with. The data variable in the AJAX call is simply a set of input text values populated elsewhere.

```
<?php

echo "Hello World";

?>
```

I guess it would be more helpful to post the full PHP script.

```
<?php
include 'dbcon.php';

if(isset($_POST['text_login_username'], $_POST['text_login_password'])) {

    $dbcon=getConnection();
    $loginUsername=$_POST['text_login_username'];
    $loginPassword=$_POST['text_login_password'];

    /*SQL INJECTION PREVENTION*/
    $loginUsername=stripslashes($loginUsername);
    $loginPassword=stripslashes($loginPassword);
    $loginUsername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$loginUsername);
    $loginPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$loginPassword);

    /*CHECK IF THERE IS A ROW WITH THIS USERNAME AND PASSWORD*/
    $sqlRequest = "SELECT * FROM userData WHERE userName='$loginUsername' and userPassword='$loginPassword'";
    $sqlRequestResult=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sqlRequest);
    $verifySqlRequest=mysqli_num_rows($sqlRequestResult); //count number of rows satisfying the request

    if($verifySqlRequest==1){
        setcookie("user",$loginUsername);
        header("location:http://localhost/mySite/dashboard.html");
        exit;   
    }
    else{
        echo "[ext.W]: Wrong user name or password..."; //THIS DOESN'T GET LOGGED.
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: What is `type`? Why do you send data? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Have you tried using your browsers debugger to verify that the ajax request is going to the correct URL?

Comment: Type is POST, and yes I used Chrome's Js console, and didn't get any errors. I will check using Firebug.

Comment: Okay, Firebug didn't catch anything either.

Comment: Make sure the network panel is open and enabled when you fire the ajax call. You should see the ajax call attempt and can view the response there.

Comment: If you are making an ajax request here you should probably return a status (ie: success/fail) and message and let the javascript handle the redirect. Since you are not actually sending the client to the server when doing an ajax request you will not be able to redirect them via php

Answer (score 0):

Well, example seems to be ok.
At first check if given URL at AJAX options responses correctly when you type it in browser.
Remember, if you want PHP to respond correctly, request should go through the Apache (or another server-side server). If browser gives you 404 (Page not found) check if Apache server is configured correctly - the URL you request should appear in Vhosts settings.

Comment: Right now I'm using localhost with OSX's builtin Apache. I have other files following the same pattern, and they all work fine.

Comment: I'll ask again - did you checked if given URL is valid? If you're testing something, don't assume anything "by default". And check if you're using some PHP framework - you didn't put "die()" after echo, so some dispaycher could re-handle it.

Comment: Yeah the given URL is fine. The file actually handles login, and it works perfectly fine if the login is valid. However, it echoes if the login is invalid, and that echo is not seen. Any echo in the file is not seen. However, the script can authenticate just fine. I've updated the question with the script.

Comment: OK, give an `else` for your main `if` in PHP. There call and `echo` like `POST vars didnt match condition`. If you'll get this, it means you haven't provided `text_login_username` and `test_login_password`. They must be passed **both** in your example by `data: {text_login_username: 'user', test_login_password: 'pass'}` in JS.

Answer (score 0):

THe problem is you are not specifying POST in your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    method : "POST", // this needs to be there! Default is GET
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```